# Birth Process - Simulation and asymptotic normality

Tags: r

**I want hat.mu_t for different times t and proof the mathematic result, that for increasing t, the estimator hat.mu_t converges to the real value mu and show the convergence in distribution mentoined above.**

So far i got this code:

```
N <- 1  ##Initial population size
simulationtime <- 1000
mu <- 0.01 ##Per capita birth rate
t <- 0    ##Initialize time
birthdat <- data.frame(t=0,N=N)  ## Place to save the results
while (t < simulationtime) {
dt <- rexp(1,rate=mu*N)              ##Time until next birth
t <- t + dt                          ##jump times
N <- N+1
birthdat <- rbind(birthdat,c(t,N))   ##Tack on the latest result
}
```

Which is the Birth Process, where the jump times and the population is stored. I have problems defining M_t, but i tried it via

```
M<-0
n<- length(birthdat[,2])-1
for (i in 1:n)
{
 M<-M+(birthdat[i+1,1]-birthdat[i,1])*birthdat[i,2]
}
hat.mu_t <- birthdat[n,2]/S #esitamtor for t is the second last jump time
```

With this method i only calculate the estimator for the second last jump time t of this simulation.

**My  little problems are:**
I would like to have X_t and M_t for arbitary times t and not for the fixed jump times, which occur in the simulation. But this is not the main problem, since i can take just the jump times as time and look how hat.mu_t changes with time and converges to mu. Problem is for longer simulationtimes the birth process explodes and i can't store all jump times and Population-size in the dataframe.

I dont know how to show the convergence in distribution as t increases.

Edit: By this sentence i mean an estimation in the sense mentoined by @effel in the comments. I would stick to effels suggestion, if there are no other suggestions. 
effel:
"Estimate mu 1000 times for t = 10, and plot the distribution of estimates. Repeat for t = 50, 100, 500 ... " and compare it to a normal distribution N(0,mu).

**Edit 2: Remark that i want to have high values of t** 
Depending on the Parameter mu a time value of t=1000 can cause high run-times of R, just for one estimate hat.mu_t. Doing this like 1000 times for a fixed time t, to plot the distribution of the estimates, will take really long. Maybe my code is not efficient enough.

Comment: Bumped up reputation above 10, please write the required LaTeX

Comment: To demonstrate convergence, I expect you'll want to run simulations of increasing length. Estimate mu 1000 times for  t = 10, and plot the distribution of estimates. Repeat for t = 50, 100, 500 ... Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Closevote Any question with "want mathematical proof" either a) belongs on either CrossValidated.com or the SE math site or b) needs to be edited to restrict the question to coding.

Comment: @42- this is just about coding. I will make it explicit.

Comment: @effel yeah, i was searching for a method to show that the convergence is true (i've showed this already mathematically). your idea is good. I can't upvote your suggestion in the comments. But your idea is really usefull.